# Find difference between timestamps in amount of custom intervals in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, plpgsql

I would like to find difference between two `timestamp`s (with timezone) in  amount of custom `interval`s. So function should be like `custom_diff(timestamptz from, timestamptz to, interval custom)`.

Keep in mind, that it is not equivalent to `(to-from)/custom` (`custom_diff('2016-08-01 00:00:00','2016-09-01 00:00:00','1 day')` is exactly 31, but `('2016-08-01 00:00:00','2016-09-01 00:00:00')/'1 day')`=`'1 month'/'1 day'` and is ambiguous).

Also I understand that in general there is no exact result of such operation (`custom_diff('2016-08-01 00:00:00','2016-09-01 00:00:00','1 month 1 day'`) so it is possible to have group of function (round-to-nearest, round-to-lower, round-to-upper and truncating, all of them should return integer number).

Is there any standard/common way for such calculation in PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL)? My main interesting is round-to-nearest function.

The best way I have invented is to iteratively add/substract `interval custom` to/from `timestamptz from` and compare with `timestamptz to`. Also it can be optimized by initially finding approximate result (for example divide [difference in seconds between `timestamp`s] for [approximation of `interval custom` in seconds]) to reduce amount of iterations.

UPD 1:

Why

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp '2016-08-01 10:00'
                     - timestamp '2016-08-01 00:00'))
 / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval '1 day');
```

is a wrong solution: lets try yourself:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( TIMESTAMPTZ '2016-01-01 utc' -
                            TIMESTAMPTZ '1986-01-01 utc' ))
            / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '1 month');
```

Result is `365.23...`. Then check result:

```
SELECT ( TIMESTAMPTZ '1986-01-01 utc' + 365 * INTERVAL '1 month' )
            AT TIME ZONE 'utc';
```

Result is `2016-06-01 00:00:00.000000`. Of cause `365` is wrong result, because timestamps in this example describe exactly 30 years and in any year always exactly 12 months, so right answer is `12*30=360`.

UPD 2:

My solution is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_diff(
    _from TIMESTAMPTZ, _to TIMESTAMPTZ, _custom INTERVAL, OUT amount INTEGER)
  RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  max_iterations INTEGER :=10;
  t              INTEGER;

BEGIN
  amount:=0;
  WHILE max_iterations > 0 AND NOT (
    extract(EPOCH FROM _to) <= ( extract(EPOCH FROM _from) + extract(EPOCH FROM _from + _custom) ) / 2
    AND
    extract(EPOCH FROM _to) >= ( extract(EPOCH FROM _from) + extract(EPOCH FROM _from - _custom) ) / 2
  ) LOOP
    -- RAISE NOTICE 'iter: %', max_iterations;
    t:=EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( _to - _from )) / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM _custom);
    _from:=_from + t * _custom;
    amount:=amount + t;
    max_iterations:=max_iterations - 1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$function$
```

but I does not sure that it is correct and still waiting for sugestion about existing/common solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get exact result after [extracting the epoch from both intervals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp '2016-08-01 10:00'
                         - timestamp '2016-08-01 00:00'))
     / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval '1 day');  -- any given interval
```

If you want rounded (truncated) result, a simple option is to cast both to `integer`. Integer division cuts off the remainder.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (ts_to - ts_from))::int
     / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval '1 day')::int;  -- any given interval
```

You can easily wrap the logic into a `IMMUTABLE` SQL function.

You are drawing the wrong conclusions from what you read in the manual. The result of a `timestamp` subtraction is an *exact* interval, storing only days and seconds (not months). So the result is exact. Try my query, it isn't "ambiguous".

You *can* avoid involving the data type `interval`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_to) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_from))
     / 86400  -- = 24*60*60 -- any given interval as number of seconds
```

But the result is the same.

Aside:

"Exact" is an elusive term when dealing with timestamps. You may have to take DST rules and other corner cases of your time zone into consideration. You might convert to UTC time or use `timestamptz` before doing the math.

Comment: You try to simplify my task to `(to-from)/custom`, but as I say it is not the same. `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval i)` in general is ambiguous (if interval internally has non zero days or months). This is why [Internally interval values are stored as months, days, and seconds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT). About «backward example»: sorry for ambigous name, it is not backward, I just mean time `[from; to]`, not `from-to`.

Comment: @Unsacrificed: I added more to address your concerns.

Comment: Lets calc: `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( TIMESTAMP '2016-03-01' - TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01' )) / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '1 month');` is `0.9(6)`, but should be exactly `1`. `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( TIMESTAMPTZ '2009-04-01 MSK' - TIMESTAMPTZ '2009-03-01 MSK' )) / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '1 hour');` is `744`, but `SELECT TIMESTAMPTZ '2009-03-01 MSK' + 744 * INTERVAL '1 hour';` is `2009-04-01 01!:00:00.00 +04:00`.
And I don’t want to convert into UTC before math because it cause different results (in Q I say `timestamp (with timezone)`) and for my task it does matter.

Comment: My second example in previous comment wrong, sorry.